# How to copy and paste specific range n times?

Tags: vba, excel

I am recently creating a macro button but I am facing difficulties in the interim.
* 'x' represents a random value
Current spreadsheet:

```
 Col:     A ................. X
 Row 1  x x x x x x x x
     2  x x x x x x x x
     3  x x x x x x x x 
     .   x x x x x x x x 
     .   x x x x x x x x 
     .   x x x x x x x x 
     .   x x x x x x x x
   16  x x x x x x x x
   17  x x x x x x x x
      .  x x x x x x x x
      .  x x x x x x x x
      .  x x x x x x x x 
      .  x x x x x x x x 
   31  x x x x x x x x
```

So basically in this case, I would like to copy the range "A2:X16" and paste it 15 times in total, right below row 16 . Afterwards, copying the original range "A17 to X31" and paste it for another 15 times in total. This process continues until all the range that I have specified has been copied 15 times in total. Is this possible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The answer to your question is: *"Yes, this is possible"*. But because Stack Overflow is no free code writing service you will need to try it on your own first. Then come back with the code you tried and tell where you got errors or where you got stuck, and ask a question to that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will copy your desired range then check for the next available empty row and paste the values there, it will loop and do this 15 times:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required

ws.Range("A2:X16").Copy

For i = 1 To 15
    NextRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    'get the Next Empty Row
    ws.Range("A" & NextRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'paste 
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks alot Xabier. I appreciate your help. I have been doing this function for a few days. Once again, thank you.