# Delete copy pasted range N times

Tags: excel, vba

[How to copy and paste specific range n times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50016229/how-to-copy-and-paste-specific-range-n-times)
Used this thread to copy and paste the range I want. Now I want to be able to delete these ranges starting from the bottom n times.

Mostly stuck on how to determine the range it is I need to clear.

Comment: Do you want to write your data in 2 columns (i.e. what you describe) or delete rows (i.e. the title of your question)? You may want to change the title to make things less ambiguous

Comment: Had 2 questions in my post as I didn't want to make a new one but for clarity I deleted the second question and will post it separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with this code you can chose how many times you will delete the range (n), and how many rows will be deleted each time (row_number)

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim n as Integer 
Dim i as Integer 

n = insert_number_of_times
row_number = number_of_rows_to_delete_each_time
i = 1

while i<=n
  last_row = ws.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row
  first_row = last_row - row_number
  ws.Range("A" & first_row & ":X" & last_row).ClearContents  'X = column reference
  i = i+1
loop
```